# how to integrate the Greensock into pixi js

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, gsap, pixi.js

Pixi’s is an extremely fast 2D sprite rendering engine and Greensock is an animation javascript library.

Has anyone used this before? If so would it integrate with GreenSock?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's an official plugin from GSAP that makes it much easier to work with Pixi: 
https://greensock.com/docs/Plugins/PixiPlugin

There are some demos in the docs. And yes, lots of people use GSAP with Pixi.

I wouldn't really recommend that other (unofficial) plugin that was mentioned in the previous post because it doesn't handle overwriting quite right, and it's not as full-featured.

Happy tweening!

Answer (score 1):

There a [library](https://github.com/noprotocol/gsap-pixi-plugin) available for integrating gsap into pixi.

```
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
TweenLite.set(sprite, { pixi: {
  //set property
}});
TweenLite.to(sprite);
```